# Abort reading from serial to start writing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, at-command

I need to "listen" on a serial port for incoming traffic and do something with it. But when the user clicks on a button, i need to write data into that serial port.

For reading incoming messages, I use ReadByte() without a Timeout. When I set the Timout an Exception would be thrown when no characters are coming (which happens most of the time!).

But this "blocks" the serial port. Now I cant write to it in an other thread (the thread that executes button click events). My current solution is killing thread that tries to read data and then starting to write data into it.

I know this is not a good way, **but what else can I do**?

I am trying to create an [AT Commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) gui application for my mobile modem.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything preventing you from writing to a port from one thread while reading from it in another - that's a completely normal thing to do.

Comment: The typical serial port is full duplex, and can transmit and receive simultaneously.  To take advantage of this you need to either use multithreading or use syscalls for nonblocking (aka asynchronous) I/O or use **select()** to determine when I/O can be performed without being blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using ReadByte() check if there are characters waiting in the buffer. Note, I am specifically looking for 10 chars.

They way I am currently doing it is:

```
int datalen = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
label1.Text="Readexisting";
if (datalen >=10)
{
    string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    label1.Text=data;
}
```